# How do I share artifacts at project level in JIRA?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

How do I share artifacts (e.g diagram and docuement) across the entire project, not just at issue level at JIRA?  Something like a common area for posting information.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities spring to mind.

Firstly you could use the HipChat integration. Sending messages via comments to a team HipChat group.

Another option would be to create a generic JIRA user with an email address that is a mailing list for your team. That way you can use the Mentions functionality to inform everyone of something.

More about the mentions functionality here: [Atlassian - Using Mentions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Mentions)

Answer (score 0):

**Use an Epic in the project**
If you are using Jira Agile you can simply create an epic (called Documentation) and house all of your documents in the epic itself or group documentation by creating subtasks in the epic to essentially create "folders". To ensure the team is seeing any changes add them all to the "watchers" list.

**Use a Confluence Space**
If you have access to Jira Confluence, just create a project space and create or link your documents there. Another benefit of using confluence is you can make these documents available to external customers (no need of a Jira account). To ensure the team is seeing any changes add them all to the "watchers" list.

Creating a Space
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/create-a-space-139463.html

**Use a Project Dashboard**
Use a dashboard and ask that your team pay attention to this every day. Dashboards are a great way to propagate information to distributed teams.

Customizing the Dashboard
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/customizing-the-dashboard-185729498.html